# Methods vs. Properties

Tags: python, methods, properties, api-design, language-design

I'm working on the Python API for our physics simulation package (Mechanica, https://mechanica.readthedocs.io), and mulling over wether to use properties or methods.

Python has an established convention that of the objects in a dictionary are accessible by an `items()` method, i.e.

```
[i for i in d.items()]
```

I'm trying to adhere to this established convention for our objects, but it's sometimes awkward, for example, in our simulator, we have:

```
C.items()                   # get all the members of this
                            # type
n = a.neighbors()           # get all the neighbors of an object
c = find_some_cluster()     # some function to find a cluster     
c.items()                   # get all the items in ths list
b = m.bind(pot, a, b)       # create a bond between two objects
b.energy()                  # gets the current energy of the bond
b.half_life                 # gets / sets the half life
b.delete()                  # deletes the bond 
b.items()[0], b.items()[1]  # gets the pair of objects that this bond acts on. 
b.dissociation_energy       # bond breaking threshold
```

To access one of the of objects a that a bond is between, you currently have to call

```
b.items()[0]
```

I think that's awkward, and perhaps `items` would be better as a property. I just don't know though, because if I made it a property, that goes agains the some of the established Python convention.  Python itself is pretty inconsistent where some things are a stand-alone function, i.e. `len(a)` for length of a list, but most other things are methods on objects.

Our bond object, some things on it are methods, like `energy()`, but others are properties, like `half_life`. I set these up this way, because half_life is actually a stateful property of the object, but `energy()` is a computed thing. I’m not sure if this makes the most sense to the end user though.
What do you guys think our `items` should be, a method or property. Is there any good rule to apply as to when something should be a method or property.

Comment: `items` isn't a convention so much as part of the mapping protocol. It's *not* necessary to name your method "items" if it isn't returning/yielding a sequence of key/value pairs.

Comment: The nice thing about a `property` is that you can start by exposing your list/set/whatever-valued attribute directly, and if you *later* want to hide it behind a getter/setter pair, you can do so without changing your class's public interface.

Comment: My personal opinion is that methods should be used where something is newly created or significant work must be done for the result. The "list.items()" creates a new iterator (in Python 2.x even a list was created).